# Globalize.format doesn't work for other locales or date formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, localization, javascript-globalize

I'm relatively new to modern Javascript (I used it all the time about a decade ago) and having problems with globalize.js.

Here's what I've got in head as it pertains to globalize

```
<script src ="{% static "js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src ="{% static "js/node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize.min.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $.get( "{% static "json/en/ca-gregorian.json" %}", Globalize.load );
    $.get( "{% static "json/de/ca-gregorian.json" %}", Globalize.load );
    $.get( "{% static "json/supplemental/likelySubtags.json" %}", Globalize.load );
    $.get( "{% static "json/supplemental/timeData.json" %}", Globalize.load );
    $.get( "{% static "json/supplemental/weekData.json" %}", Globalize.load );
    console.log("short:" + Globalize.format( new Date( 2010, 10, 30, 17, 55 ), { datetime: "short" }));
    console.log("medium:" + Globalize.format( new Date( 2010, 10, 30, 17, 55 ), { datetime: "medium" }));
    console.log("long:" + Globalize.format( new Date( 2010, 10, 30, 17, 55 ), { datetime: "long" }, "de" ));
</script>
```

And here's the output:

```
short:11/30/2010 5:55:00 PM (index):21
medium:11/30/2010 5:55:00 PM (index):22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of null
```

As you can see, I'm running into two problems - the {datetime: } parameter seems to not affect the output at all. More importantly, I can't figure out why it can't translate the dates into other languages. Am I missing an include? Other threads on their issue list pointed towards this being all I needed in order to localize dates.

Comment: It may be that you're missing the date.js module. Dates... *shivers*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this instead:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('de', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })
```

or even:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString(Globalize.culture().name, { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })
```

`Globalize.culture().name` assumes you have added the possible cultures to Globalize either manually or by importing a `globalize.culture.{culture}[.min].js` file for each of them, such as `globalize.culture.fr.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Follow examples of using Globalize 1.x:

- [Hello World (AMD + bower)](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/examples/amd-bower).
- [Hello World (Node.js + npm)](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/examples/node-npm).
- [Hello World (plain JavaScript)](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/examples/plain-javascript).

There's also an example of using `$.get` calls to load CLDR data dynamically at [globalize.js: dynamic loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946511/globalize-js-dynamic-loading/30237525#30237525)

Please, just let me know if you have any questions.