# globalize.js: dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-globalize

I am trying to the example for plain JS of the gloablize (https://github.com/jquery/globalize) running in an advanced way based on https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/cldr.md.

Therefore I created a loader script to load all dependencies:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
//STATIC_URL: global variable from base.html
$.when( 
        $.getScript( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/cldrjs/cldr.js" ),
        $.getScript( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/cldrjs/cldr/event.js" ),
        $.getScript( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/cldrjs/cldr/supplemental.js" ),
        $.getScript( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/globalize.js" ),
        $.getScript( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/globalize/date.js" ),
        $.getScript( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/globalize/number.js" ),
        $.getScript( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/globalize/plural.js" ),

        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        })
).done(function(){
    $.when(
      $.get( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/cldr/main/de/ca-gregorian.json" ),
      $.get( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json" ),
      $.get( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json" ),
      $.get( url.origin + STATIC_URL + "js/globalize2/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json" )
    ).then(function() {

      // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
      return [].slice.apply( arguments, [ 0 ] ).map(function( result ) {
          return result[ 0 ];
      });

    }).then( Globalize.load ).then(function() {

      // Your code goes here.

    }); 
});
```

All files are loaded correctly as far as i can see in Firebug.
But when it comes to the `Globalize.load` step, the reference is marked as not defined.

I don't have a clue whats wrong at the moment.
Any help welcome.

Comment: dont know globalize but from a pure JS point of view you would probably need to instantiate Globalize?? the doc you have linked also does this

Comment: they do it like this in the docs: var en = Globalize( "en" );.... en.formatDate( new Date(), ... and so on